# Blinking animaton with color change when the value of Recyclerview item's TextView change

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-animation, android-adapter

I have a `Recyclerview` and I want to have blinking animation with color change anytime the `TextView` text value of any row changes and at the end of the animation, I want the `TextView` to have its initial color back.

```
class EventsAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<EventsAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    var events: List<Event> = emptyList()
        set(value) {
            DiffUtil.calculateDiff(EventsDiffUtil(events, value))
                .dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
            field = value
        }

    private lateinit var animation: Animation

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val binding = EventItemBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)

        animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(parent.context, R.anim.blink)

        return ViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = events.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(events[position])
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(
        val binding: EventItemBinding
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(event: Event) {
            with(binding) {

                nameTv.text = event.name

                if (!countTv.text.isNullOrBlank())
                    countTv.startAnimation(animation)

                countTv.text = event.count.toString()
            }
        }
    }
}

class EventsDiffUtil(
    private val oldList: List<Event>,
    private val newList: List<Event>
) : DiffUtil.Callback() {

    override fun getOldListSize(): Int = oldList.size

    override fun getNewListSize(): Int = newList.size

    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldPosition: Int, newPosition: Int): Boolean {
        return oldList[oldPosition].id == newList[newPosition].id
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldPosition: Int, newPosition: Int): Boolean {
        return oldList[oldPosition] == newList[newPosition]
    }
}
```

I am able to get the blinking animation working but I am not sure if that is the proper way of doing it and I have no idea how can make the color changes. I know I can use the `AnimationListener` interface but not sure how and where to set it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You could use notify item changed with payload notifyItemChanged(int position, Object payload). After that, implement that method onBindViewHolder(VH holder, int position, List payloads). If the item is visible when you want to play animation on the item, you can handle the animation in onBind I added above. As payload you should use your animation color then play animation in onBind.